# Evaluating JPA providers: Market share of Hibernate/EclipseLink?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, eclipselink

I'm struggling to find some data as to the (estimated) number of installations/user base/market share of Hibernate and/or EclipseLink.

This information would help in interpreting numbers like '# of bug reports opened' or '# of S/O questions' per product, but it seems that's not as readily available as I would expect.

Can anyone point me to some resources in this regard?

Comment: How would you judge market share that isn't subjective or opinionated?  Market share questions generally get closed on stack overflow for these reasons.

Comment: and indeed, what use does it have, other than allowing people to follow like sheep of course, rather than doing a real assessment based on capabilities

Comment: @Chris What do you mean? If there are meaningful figures about the relative use of programming languages, why shouldn't there be some about JPA providers?

Comment: @NeilStockton You can trust me that I know how to interpret the numbers right. And we all know that there's more to different technologies than the capabilities present at a given instant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [RebelLabs 2014 java tools and technologies report](http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/java-tools-and-technologies-landscape-for-2014/10/), Hibernate was having a 67.5% market share, meaning that all other providers combined share less than 1/3 of the whole market.

The 2014 Data Access frameworks market share is:

- Hibernate : 67.5%
- Plain JDBC : 22%
- JDBC Template : 19.5%
- EclipseLink : 13%
- MyBatis : 6.5%
- JOOQ : 1.5%
- Other : 7%

In a [2016 survey](https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-providers-market-share-in-2016/), the following results have been obtained:

- Hibernate : 72%
- EclipseLink : 13%
- OpenJPA : 2%

Comment: I knew that data must have been somewhere! ;-) Will have a look at it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I updated the link and the full ORM statistics result.